# How to Telnet in Azure API Management Instance

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I want to test the back-end connectivity from the Azure API Management instance but not sure how to do that.. Is there any command I can try from the Azure bash or any other way to test connectivity

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "test backend connectivity"?

There's an entire 'test' functionality suite in API-M which, in my opinion, negates the need for this.

[Here's a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector) which goes into some detail.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean to check and endpoint with curl command or check the endpoint with telnet command like we execute "telnet <hostname> <port_no>" in Linux. I am looking something similar to this, The link you shared, that needs proxy creation and then only we can test it.